# how to put validation using script in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: validation

i want to set validation using multiple fields in Newitem.aspx. e.g. if user select type "Sick leave" and number of days are > 3 then he must add "attachment". i tried with presave action but it's only supporting for attachment validation whereas i want to add two more conditions.

can anyone guide me in this regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it in PreSaveAction as well. Something like this? just set your 2 other variables you care about, using javascript or jquery.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function PreSaveAction() {
           var type = $('input[Title="Field Name"]').val();
           var numberDays = ......
           var elm = document.getElementById("idAttachmentsTable");

if (type == 'Sick leave' && numberDays > 3 && (elm == null || elm.rows.length == 0))
{
               document.getElementById("idAttachmentsRow").style.display='none';

alert("Please attach Documents");
return false ;
}
else { return true ;}
}
</script>
```